# Possible bug in Chrome - Video controls are still visible when using backface-visibility:hidden on HTML5 videos

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I found a possible bug in Chrome.

Basically HTML5 native video controls are still visible when using backface-visibility:hidden on HTML5 video tag.

To reproduce it, click 12 times on the button in the example below.

Problem is visible on:

- Google Chrome Version 56.0.2924.87 (64-bit)
- Google Chrome Version 59.0.3033.0 canary (64-bit) (CANARY)

Test case works on:

- Firefox 52.0 (64-bit)
- Firefox 53.0a2 (2017-03-06) (64-bit)

I would like to know if you have faced this issue before and a possible work around to it.

PS: I am aware that could created some custom video controls, but I prefer to use the native ones.

```js
let elmBtn = document.getElementById('btn');
let elmVideo = document.getElementById('video');
let elmBox = document.getElementById('box');
let rotateY = 0;
// start style
elmVideo.style.transform = `scaleZ(1) translateZ(-500px) rotateY(${rotateY}deg)`;
elmVideo.style.backfaceVisibility = 'hidden';

elmBox.style.transform = `scaleZ(1) translateZ(-500px) rotateY(${rotateY}deg)`;
elmBox.style.backfaceVisibility = 'hidden';

elmBtn.addEventListener('click', event => {
  rotateY += 10;
  elmVideo.style.transform = `scaleZ(1) translateZ(-500px) rotateY(${rotateY}deg)`;
  elmBox.style.transform = `scaleZ(1) translateZ(-500px) rotateY(${rotateY}deg)`;
});
```

```css
#wrapper {
  perspective: 1000px;
}

#box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#btn {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <video id="video" preload="metadata" controls>
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="http://html5demos.com/assets/dizzy.ogv" type="video/ogg">
  </video>
  <div id="box"></div>
</div>
<button id="btn">Click me to rotate</button>
```

Comment: backface-visibility: hidden has been buggy in Chrome for *years*. A similar problem exists on my home page. Unlike with IE, there is no known fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the controls with this little JavaScript:

```
var vid = document.getElementById(id);
vid.controls = false;
```

and this to make them visible again:

```
vid.controls = true;
```

I hope you can you use this workaround.